# JQuery mobile Square/Circular styling

Tags: jquery-mobile

In my application I create a few buttons using D3 functions, but when they're displayed they do not have the circular borders like the hard coded buttons do:

"Menu" is hard coded, the other four buttons are from D3 functions
[image]

I first thought I had screwed up the classes of the buttons, but they do have the `ui-corner-all` class:
[image]

Why aren't they getting styled correctly? (There is no custom CSS applied besides the red text)
They should look along the lines of these examples:
http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.2/checkboxradio-radio/

Edit:
Here's the D3 function:

```
this.initialLoad = function(){
        //var data= ["First button with some long text in the descriptionnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn", "Second button with some long text in the description"];

        console.log("initialLoad");
        //Create the header
        headerElem = d3.select("#uploadedCompany")
        .append("p");
        //add the required buttons for selecting the right sheet for the set
        var Addedbuttons = d3.select("#TheButtons").selectAll("input")
            .data(
                            function (){
                var titlelist = Array();
                for (var n = 0; n < numOfSheets; n++){
                    titlelist[n]= upLoadedData[n].title;
                }
                return titlelist;
            }
                    )
            .enter()
            .append('label')
            .attr('for',function(d,i){ return 'Statement_a'+i; })
            .text(function(d) { return d; })
            .append("input")    
            .attr("type", "radio")
            .attr("name","stmntRadio")
            .property('checked',function (d,i){if (i===pSI) return true; else return              `false;})`  
            .attr("id", function(d,i) { return i; })
            .attr("onClick", "rbStatementClicked(this)");

        //make sure that the  trendON is false
        d3.select("#cbTrendOn").node().checked = false;         
        updateSheet();
                    $("#TheButtons").enhanceWithin();
    };
```

Comment: Show us your code that creates the buttons or create a fiddle that reproduces the issue. If you want, you can edit and update this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/7fnzubbt/

Comment: I can't recreate it. All of them end up circular/different from what I have now.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your #TheButtons DOM element is setup as a controlgroup with data-type="horizontal".  In that case you just need to add .controlgroup("refresh") after the enhance within. Also, add the dynamic controls to the .ui-controlgroup-controls DIV within the controlgroup.

```
var Addedbuttons = d3.select("#TheButtons .ui-controlgroup-controls ").selectAll("input")
            .data(data)
            .enter()
            .append("input")    
            .attr("type", "radio")
            .attr("name","stmntRadio")
            .attr("id", function(d,i) { return 'Statement_a'+i; })
            .attr("onClick", "rbStatementClicked(this)")
            .append('label')
            .attr('for',function(d,i){ return 'Statement_a'+i; })
            .text(function(d) { return d; })
;

$("#TheButtons").enhanceWithin().controlgroup("refresh");
```

> Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/7fnzubbt/2/)**